# If not an upper bound, is it a lower bound?

Tags: asymptotics

I wanted some help with a bounding question. The question asks that if $f$ is not an upper bound on $g$, is it a lower bound? $f,g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$.

By definition for an upper bound, there exists a constant $c$, there exists a constant $n_0$ such that $f(n) \le c \cdot g(n)$ for all $n > n_0$.

Negating that suggests for all $c$, for all $n_0$, $f(n) > c\cdot g(n)$.

So it would seem like the statement is true, but is it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try $g(n) = n$ and $f(n) = 0$ for even $n$ and $f(n) = n!$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Your don't negate the statement correct. It would be:
$\exists n>n_0$ such that $f(n)>c\cdot g(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ odd}\\n&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$
$$g(n)=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ even}\\n&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is neither an upper nor a lower bound for $g$ in the sense of your question.
Whatever positive real $c$ (and natural $n_0$ ) you choose, $f(n)\le cg(n)$ becomes false as soon as $n>c$ (and $n_0$) is even and  $f(n)\ge cg(n)$ becomes false as soon as $n>\frac1c$ (and $n_0$) is odd.

Note that the negation of
$$ \exists c\exists n_0\forall n>n_0\colon f(n)\le cg(n)$$
is rather
$$ \forall c\forall n_0\exists n>n_0\colon f(n)> cg(n)$$
and that is not the definition of lower bound.